# Using a Javascript switch statement, how can I count the number of elements (numbers only) in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to count the number of elements (*numbers only*) in an array using a **switch statement** in the function. I honestly don't know exactly what this code would look like. But this is what I have so far

```
<script language="JavaScript">
//an array of numbers
var number = [1,"o",2,3,"a",0];
//a switch statement

switch (number) {
    //Not sure what would go here....

    break;
}
  //display result of count
alert(count)
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use a switch statement here?

Comment: Is this some sort of exercise?

Comment: This is one of the worst questions i have seen on here where people are fighting in the solutions and there are already -14 in votes across this. Don't give the guy a hard time, use it to educate and not ridicule.

Comment: Regardless of what you use for the checking (switch, if statement, etc) you must iterate through the array. This can be done using a for loop, while/do while loop or recursion. ```!isNaN(input)``` function will test if a given input is a Number. !isNaN(false), !isNaN("2.1") are both numbers. However, if you strictly want to 'number' types you can test this using ```typeof input == "number"```

Comment: I appreciate the comments Shawn.

Comment: @Shawn I think you're overreacting. Nobody is fighting (does anything really look aggressive?) and the downvotes are perfectly fine because a simple google search would have shown how to use a switch statement. Not to mention the switch is rather.. redundant since a for loop could tell you the same thing.

Comment: ^ I retract that first part. It's a little ugly towards the bottom LOL

Comment: I haven't read all the comments on the answers, but @user3097967 why on earth do you **have** to do this with a switch statement?

Comment: I'm up-voting this question.

Comment: I'm downvoting only because the OP refuses to tell why the switch requirement.

Comment: He told why actually : "it's more fun this way :D". Hahaha! Ahem... Very funny indeed.

Comment: @wared That wasn't the OP.

Comment: @wared I'm pretty sure it wasn't a reply to the comment but to the answer itself. (No way to know for sure, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Okay! A switch! Let's do it!

```
var count = 0;
for(var i = number.length; i--;){
    switch(true){
        case typeof number[i] == 'number':
            count++;
    }
}
alert(count);
```

Comment: annd... where's a `switch`?

Comment: Hmm... why not switch on `typeof number[i]`? :-)

Comment: It's more fun this way :D

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks nderscore :)

Comment: @user3097967 why don't you like Matt's answer?

Comment: It didnt work for me a moment ago....seems like they both are working now

Comment: Why would you use filter rather than reduce? No reason to create another array... ([speed test](http://jsperf.com/array-filter-length-vs-reduce))

Comment: @JanDvorak Lol... You don't only tell people what to answer or not to answer, you also tell them who they should accept... Funny to see you in the list of moderators who marked this question as off-topic then...

Answer (score 5):

> using a switch statement

if you insist:

```
var count = 0;
for( var i=0 ; i<number.length ; ++i )
    switch( typeof(number[i]) ) {
        case "number": ++count; break;
    }
```

`count` has value `4`.

Note: `NaN`, `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`, and `Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY` are also `"number"`s, so if you don't want to count these then do

```
var count = 0;
for( var i=0 ; i<number.length ; ++i )
    switch( typeof number[i] ) {
        case "number":
            if( !isNaN(number[i]) && isFinite(number[i]) )
                ++count;
    }
```

Comment: the `break` is redundant, but if you insist...

Comment: @JanDvorak Lol, you're absolutely right..

Comment: The `()` around the typeof operators are redundant, but if you insist...

Answer (score 3):

I think the current answers are not very compact.

Here is my take, using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var number = [1,"o",2,3,"a",0];

var count = number.reduce(function(accum,cur){
    return accum+(typeof cur === "number");
});
```

Here is a take using the required `switch`

```
var number = [1,"o",2,3,"a",0];

var count = number.reduce(function(accum,cur){
    return accum+(typeof cur === "number");
    switch(true){} // this switch's name is Alfred, after Batman's butler
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = [1,"o",2,3,"a",0];
var nums = 0;
for(var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(typeof a[i] == "number") nums++;
}
alert(nums);
```

Comment: Where's a `switch`? (didn't downvote)

Comment: `nums.length` is what he wants, I think.

Comment: No switch is necessary here.

Comment: The OP seems to want it as indicated in bold in the question.

Comment: The array is a mixture of strings and numbers and what not else (maybe apples and oranges also?).

Comment: @m59 `nums` is already a number here

Comment: @JanDvorak ahh sorry, I thought he did what I was thinking of - I would have created a new array containing the numbers and checked the length.

Comment: @m59 that would have been inefficient

Comment: @JanDvorak depends on the broader context, but I wasn't debating that anyway. You are correct.